# How to mount a local ROS package into a docker container to be used

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, ros, gazebo-simu

I am using ROS noetic and have both a local workspace and a docker image/container that I have been given with gazebo worlds and launch files, the container does not have teleop keyboard installed and I would like to use it for one of the models simulation. I have a local ws that I have volume mounted into the container so that I can run rospy scripts, however I install and catkin_make the local workspace with teleop_twist_keyboard able to compile and run yet when inside the docker container it does not recognize the ros package or allow me to catkin_make the mounted space, only the docker one. How can I go about using my local workspace with full functionality within the docker container ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you are missing a source to your mounted volume inside the docker container. Otherwise, you could probably set the environment variables 'ROS_MASTER_URI' and 'ROS_IP' inside and outside the container to send commands. You might have some delays with that approach, though